# A modern alternative to html/CSS tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I vaguely remember reading about some new (CSS3?) type of tables. The problem mentioned at the time was that it wasn't widely supported. Is there anything like that? Is it support better today? Sorry I can't be more specific, I don't remember its name.

The bottom line is that I'm trying to get div's to be equally sized horizontally next to each other, but when I do that using `display: table` (and `display: table-cell` in the `li`'s) - they ignore things (like `overflow: hidden` ).

Comment: Are you looking for CSS3 flexboxes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes. Thanks! You can transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: It's alright, I'm sure someone else will post it as an answer. This question is a little broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198954/a-modern-alternative-to-html-css-tables/29199071#comment46610311_29198954) above - [CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) is it.

Comment: And there's also CSS grid. But [hardly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) yet.

Answer (score 0):

try this. There are some more types like given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

```
{display:flex;}
```

Still, I will suggest you to play with tables. They are awesome, just need some tweaks.